# Python: pivot a pandas DataFrame when the desired index Series has duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame `my_data` that looks like

```
    event_id    user_id    attended
0     13          345         1
1     14          654         0
...
```

So `event_id` and `user_id` both have duplicates because there is an entry for each user and event combination. What I want to do is reshape this into a DataFrame where my indices (rows) are the DISTINCT `user_id`'s, the columns are the DISTINCT `event_id`'s and the values in a given (row, col) is just the boolean 0 or 1 of whether they attended.

It seems that the `pivot` method is appropriate but of course when I tried `my_data.pivot(index='user_id', columns='event_id', values='attended')` I got the error that the index has duplicates.

I was thinking I should do some kind of `groupby` on the `user_id`'s first but I don't want to add up all the `attended` 1's and 0's for each user because I specifically want to separate the `event_id`'s as my new columns and keep separate which event was attended by each user.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, `pivot_table` should give you what you want:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"event_id": np.random.randint(10, 20, 20), "user_id": np.random.randint(100, 110, 20), "attended": np.random.randint(0, 2, 20)})
>>> df.pivot_table(index="user_id", columns="event_id", values="attended", 
    aggfunc=sum).fillna(0)
event_id  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  19
user_id                                     
101        0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
103        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
104        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
105        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
106        0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
107        1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
108        0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
109        0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
```

As written, if there are multiple rows with the same user/event combination (which probably isn't the case) the attendance will be summed.  It's easy enough to use `any` or clip the values instead if you want to guarantee the frame consists only of 0s and 1s.

Comment: thanks for the help but one follow-up question if you don't mind: when I look at the resulting pivot tables columns or index I get just the event_id or user_id numbers...so what are event_id and user_id in the new pivot table? the resulting thing from calling pivot table is a DataFrame so how would I access these identifiers for example? Just trying to understand where they are stored in the new DataFrame. Thanks!

Comment: If you're asking where the strings `"event_id"` and `"user_id"` are stored, they're in `df.columns.name` and `df.index.name`, respectively.

Comment: Also, you can pass `fill_value=0` as a kwarg to `pivot_table()` instead of calling `fillna(0)` after pivoting.